# jQuery - When you delegate an event handler, will it also auto-remove itself from elements that no longer match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handler

Assume the following structure

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div class="selected"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="selected"></div>
</div>
```

I want to assign a delegated event handler to all .selected elements, so that when new elements are selected, they automatically receive the handler.

```
$("div#wrapper").on("click", "div.selected", function() {
    //do magic
});
```

Now, every time a new div is selected, it will automatically receive the handler.

**BUT**, if I ***unselect*** a div (remove the .selected class), will it also automatically drop the handler?

Comment: By "unselect," do you mean remove the `selected` class?

Comment: Yes I do. I'll clear that up

Comment: *"...will it also automatically drop the handler?"* I think you're misunderstanding event delegation. Handlers are not assigned to the new `div.selected` elements. The only handler is on `div#wrapper`, and it manages the click events inside it.

Comment: Oh. Is it basically an alias for $("div#wrapper").click(function() { $this.find("div.selected").each(function() {//do magic}); });

Comment: Not literally, no, but you're thinking along the right lines.

Comment: Like Blazemonger suggested, not quite, but you're close. When an event takes place, you have the `this`, which refers to the bound element, and then the `event.target` which refers to the actual nested element that received the event. What jQuery does is that it takes the `event.target`, and checks to see if it matches your `div.selected` selector. If it does, it invokes your handler, manually setting the `this` value to that element. It then continues up to its `.parentNode` and does the same thing, up and up until it gets to the `div#wrapper` where it stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct -- your code

```
$("div#wrapper").on("click", "div.selected", function() {
    //do magic
});
```

should be read as: "When a click occurs in `div#wrapper`, if (and only if) it is on a `div.selected` element, run this function."

In other words, your event handler is *actually* bound to `div#wrapper`, not on the `div.selected` elements inside of it. So you can add or remove `div.selected` as you like and the delegated handler will automatically be triggered on them as needed.